# Font padding problems with Droid font in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create some 9patch images that have some text as their content. I define the stretchable area with a black pixel line top and left. And I define the content area with a black pixel line right and bottom.

However, it seems as though Droid is adding padding to the top and bottom of the content area, messing my layouts up. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

You say you're putting a black pixel *line* for the top and left? For the top, you should place just a single pixel for the stretch point. For the left, you can place either one or two pixels (two if there are two separate places you would like to stretch). Let me know if I am misunderstanding you though.